# I'm trying to upgrade php 5.3 to 5.6 on Ubunt 12.04, but getting error when trying to install anything

Tags: php, upgrade, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to upgrade php 5.3 to 5.6 on Ubunt 12.04, but getting error when trying to install anything:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_TIME = "tr_TR.UTF-8",
LC_MONETARY = "tr_TR.UTF-8",
LC_ADDRESS = "tr_TR.UTF-8",
LC_TELEPHONE = "tr_TR.UTF-8",
LC_NAME = "tr_TR.UTF-8",
LC_MEASUREMENT = "tr_TR.UTF-8",
LC_IDENTIFICATION = "tr_TR.UTF-8",
LC_NUMERIC = "tr_TR.UTF-8",
LC_PAPER = "tr_TR.UTF-8",
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up slapd (2.4.28-1.1ubuntu4.6) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Omitting slapd configuration as requested.
* No configuration file was found for slapd at /etc/ldap/slapd.conf.
invoke-rc.d: initscript slapd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing slapd (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
slapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and when i'm trying to add this repertory:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5.6
```

i'm getting following error:

```
Cannot access PPA 
(https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ondrej/+archive/php5.6) to get PPA 
information, please check your internet connection.
```

Any help please?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 reached it's "end of life" in April 2017... https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life